# Not able to build .ipa file in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I am facing an error when I am trying to build the .ipa file in #Flutter Project and the project is running perfectly when I am using a real iOS device. Please let me know if anyone can connect with me and help me to solve this error - this is my pastebin code `mDRHdD1W`

Comment: pastebin code not working

Comment: Please check this https://pastebin.com/mDRHdD1W

Comment: Please  clear derived data first. then flutter clean. flutter pub get. cd ios. pod install. pod update then try to build ios app

Comment: Tried the suggested solution but the log is same.

Comment: can you please  copy this project to another locationa  and try same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.